# Unity is very low speeds In Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, recovery-mode, clutterflow

My system specs are as follows:

- Ram: 3GB
- CPU: AMD Sempron (tm) Processor 140 Processor 2.69 Ghz
- Graphic: Nvidia GeForce 9400 GT 1Gb

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04, and Unity is working very slow. Dash or right click to open any other application is delayed. I have not yet installed the graphics card. At the time of installation, I did not connect to the Internet.

Comment: you mean you installed ubuntu **13.04**, right? If yes, then please update the question.

Comment: "I have not yet installed the graphics card." What?! What is this: Nvidia GeForce 9400 GT 1Gb if not a graphics card. If you really don't have a graphics card then that will be why.

Answer (score 1):

You should install nvidia drivers (free and nonfree) and install them. See if that works.

Comment: Which ones should OP install, he can only use one graphics driver at a time.